# I am facing issue while installation of UI Path?

Tags: rpa, uipath

2019-04-18 22:42:52> Unhandled exception: System.BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The module was expected to contain an assembly manifest.
File name: 'WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.executeCommandLine(String[] args)
   at Squirrel.Update.Program.main(String[] args)

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].

Comment: Not much information to go on, what version are you installing? What installer package are you using? What steps do you take to produce to the error? I might suggest reaching out to UiPath Support directly or on their forums.

Answer (score 0):

In order to install UiPath you need Microsoft .net framework 4.6.2 or above.

If you do not have Microsoft .net framework installed please download it and install it from the following link:

[Microsoft .net framework](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=48137)

And then try to install UiPath.

Hope this will be helpful.